# How to mock a method so whenever called it returns same result in NSubstitute

Tags: c#, .net, testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I am using NSubstitute nuget package for mocking in my .NET 6 testing project.

I am mocking a method return like this :

```
var resulttttt = authService.GetToken().Returns(mockedResult);
```

Then I create an instance of required service

```
var tokenService = _injection.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITokenService>();
```

This call internally calls GetToken which we mocked earlier, but it does not return mockedResult instead it again makes a call

```
var result = await tokenService.ValidateToken(token);
```

How can I force it to returned mocked result whenever called.